# .NET TextHelper

Tags: .net, ruby

Are there any helpers available for .NET similar to Ruby's `TextHelper`?  I think .NET 4.0 Entity Framework has functions similar to `TextHelper`, but I am working with a .NET 2.0 legacy program and would like to know if there are any text helpers that I could use.

Comment: can you explain what exactly you need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC ActionPack may have what you're looking for http://mvcactionpack.codeplex.com/ 
They have a TextHelper utility class http://mvcactionpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/34116#374927

Comment: Actually, I am looking for something like their Inflector class.  I will try that.  Thanks!